# Postgres serial datatype for primary key returns null when sending json request from postman?

Tags: sql, node.js, json, postgresql, postman

Stack: nodejs, expressjs, postgresql, postman for testing requests

My Postman request encounters an error that does not pass the JSON correctly. I get the error:

> null value in column "productid" of relation "product" violates not-null constraint

Right now in the json body of my post request in postman:

```
{
    "productID": "1",
    "productName": "pH Cleanser", 
    "price": 25.0,
    "quantity": 20
}
```

However I get an error: error: null value in column "productid" of relation "product" violates not-null constraint

```
  detail: 'Failing row contains (null, pH Cleanser, 25, 20, 2022-01-12 14:34:48.604451, 2022-01-12 14:34:48.604451).',
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: 'public',
  table: 'product',
  column: 'productid',
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
```

My table in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE product 
(
    productID serial PRIMARY KEY,
    productName VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    price FLOAT NOT NULL,
    quantity  INT NOT NULL,
    createdAt timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updatedAt timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

What do I do with a serial data type when passing a JSON request? I thought I could put an integer manually but its invalid.

I can manually insert into the database from the terminal.

Comment: Check your app controller mapping the json to sql command.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are explicitly attempting to insert a null value into your primary key column. You should write the insert statement to either not include the productID column or to insert the postgres keyword DEFAULT. This will allow postgres to auto generate the id on insert.  You can then retrieve the newly generated id from the postgres library you are using.